# Pytest - spying method calls on a dependent object

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock, spying

```
class Work:
    pass
```

```
class Engineer:

   def delegate(work: Work):
       print('Doing all the hard work')
```

```
class Manager:

   def __init__(self, engineer: Engineer):
       self.engineer = engineer

   def perform(work: Work):
       self.engineer.delegate(work)
```

I want to test `Manager`'s perform() method. In doing so I want to verify if `engineer.delegate()` method was called with the right params:

```
    # pseudo 

    work = mock(Work)
    engr = mock(Engineer)

    mgr = spy(Manager)
    mgr.perform(work)

    verify(engr.delegate).times(1).capture(args)
    assert args == work
```

I can't seem to wrap my head over how the above can be accomplished with pytest and pytest-mock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you inject your dependencies into your `Manager` class it is straight-forward to test. As noted in your pseudo-code we just need to create some mocks for the dependencies and then we can use [`spy`](https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#spy) to verify number of calls and the arguments the functions were called with.

One thing to mention, in your `Manager.perform` function definition, you forgot to include `self` as being one of the arguments passed in.

```
from src.manager import Manager, Engineer, Work


def test_manager_delegation(mocker):
    mock_engineer = mocker.Mock(spec=Engineer)
    mock_work = mocker.Mock(spec=Work)
    manager = Manager(mock_engineer)

    perform_spy = mocker.spy(manager, "perform")
    delegate_spy = mocker.spy(mock_engineer, "delegate")
    manager.perform(mock_work)

    perform_spy.assert_called_once_with(mock_work)
    delegate_spy.assert_called_once_with(mock_work)
```

---

```
=========================================== test session starts ===========================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.9, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: ***
plugins: asyncio-0.18.3, hypothesis-6.48.1, mock-3.7.0
asyncio: mode=strict
collected 1 item                                                                                          

tests/test_manager.py .                                                                             [100%]

============================================ 1 passed in 0.01s ============================================
```

Comment: Thanks :). Unfortunately for me `delegate_spy.assert_called_once_with(mock_work)` threw AssertionError (with no useful message to help troubleshoot). However, `assert delegate_spy.call_count() == 1` worked. Any clue?

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind. This post http://engineroom.trackmaven.com/blog/mocking-mistakes/ explains why.